# Get next day delivery time, but without sunday PHP / Wordpress Function

Tags: php, wordpress, date

Im using function for display estimate delivery time like this:

```
// [tomorrow]  
function displaydate_tomorrow(){  
return date_i18n('l, j. F', strtotime('+1 day')); 
}  
add_shortcode('tomorrow', 'displaydate_tomorrow'); 
// end tomorrows date
```

and it works very well, but the problem is that I need to exclude "Sunday" from string. Is there possible to do that.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first check if tomorrow is Sunday or not. If it was Sunday give the next two days not the next day.

```
function displaydate_tomorrow(){  
    $i = date('l', strtotime('+1 day')) == 'Sunday' ? 2 : 1;        

    return date_i18n('l, j. F', strtotime("+$i day")); 
}
```